# C# check if two computers are in a trusted domain (or: decide which authentication mechanism for winrm connection)

Tags: c#, authentication, kerberos, winrm, negotiate

I want to connect via winrm to other computers. I got only the FQDN of the destination computer which i want to connect. I have no information of the destination whether it is in a trusted Domain.
So the basic question is how do i now which Authentication mechanism is needed to connect?
Are there any C# .NET methods to check that?

Or is the easier way to set the authentication mechanism to kerberos, and if it fails set it to negotiate?

```
WSManConnectionInfo wci = new WSManConnectionInfo(TargetUri, ShellUri.ToString(), Credential);
wci.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/0a5cb5a4-317c-4fcd-9221-85884af1217f

```
//Trusts for current domain
Domain currentDomain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
var domainTrusts = currentDomain.GetAllTrustRelationships();
```